# how to set the overridden block file to template file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

i have overridden the **Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register** block .now my new block file **Webkul\Hello\Block\Form\Register**

customer_account_create.xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Magento_Customer::/form/register.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

above code is core xml file.

what xml code i have to write to update block file of template and where i have to insert that code

i have tried this code snippet

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
   <block class="Webkul\Hello\Block\Form\Register" template="Magento_Customer::/form/register.phtml" />
 </referenceBlock>
```

but not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to create di.xml fiule in your module

**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/di.xml**

add below code to this file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" type="Webkul\Hello\Block\Form\Register" />
</config>
```

Comment: Yeah..I have overridden the block file this di.xml.i have customer _accout_create.xml file in my custom theme folder.thats is the problem in my scenario

Comment: you have to override core block using di.xml. Go with nit will solve your issue